# Не видно флешки в Boot Menu

Tags: ubuntu, bios, boot

3 месяца назад перешел с windows на ubuntu. Сегодня нужно было загрузиться с флешки. Я записал на нее образ и зашел в boot menu. Но флешки там просто не было в пунктах загрузки. Помогите! Ноутбук dell inspiron 5567

Comment: Вы просто скачали (распаковали) на нее образ, или сделали загрузочной?

Comment: Похоже, что этот ноутбук понимает только UEFI флешки, советуют rufus, https://www.dell.com/community/Windows-10/Dell-Inspiron-15-7567-won-t-boot-from-USB/td-p/5162752

Comment: У меня такой HP envy, со второго HDD можно только через UEFI загрузится

Comment: вот вроде оно, но сам не пробовал: https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Comment: Все работает,благодарю за ответ.